# Developing Regular Expression to my needs

Tags: regex, asp-classic, vbscript

I'm really bad with regular expressions and find them to be too complex. However, I need to use them to do some string manipulation in classic asp.

*Input String :*

```
"James John Junior 

S.D. Industrial Corpn  
D-2341, Focal Point, Phase 4-a, 
Sarsona, Penns
Japan
Phone : 92-161-4633248 Fax : 92-161-253214
email : swerte_60@laher.com"
```

*Desired Output string:*

```
"JXXXX JXXX JXXXXX 

S.X. IXXXXXXXXX CXXXX  
D-XXXX, FXXXX PXXXX, PXXXX 4-X, 
SXXXXXX, PXXXX
JXXXX
PXXXX : 9X-XXX-XXXXXXX Fax : 9X-XXX-XXXXXX
eXXXX : sXXXXX_XX@XXXXX.XXX"
```

Note: We need to split the original string into words based on a single space Then, in those words, we need to replace all letters (lower and upper case) and numbers except for the first character in each word with an "X"

I know its sort of difficult, but a seasoned RegEx expert could nail this pretty easily I would think. No?

Edit:

I've made some progress. Found a function (http://www.addedbytes.com/lab/vbscript-regular-expressions/) that sort of does the job. But needs a little refinement, if anyone can help

```
function ereg_replace(strOriginalString, strPattern, strReplacement, varIgnoreCase) 
' Function replaces pattern with replacement 
' varIgnoreCase must be TRUE (match is case insensitive) or FALSE (match is case sensitive) 
dim objRegExp : set objRegExp = new RegExp 
 with objRegExp 
    .Pattern = strPattern 
    .IgnoreCase = varIgnoreCase 
    .Global = True 
end with 
ereg_replace = objRegExp.replace(strOriginalString, strReplacement) 
set objRegExp = nothing 
end function
```

Im calling it like so -

```
orgstr = ereg_replace(orgstr, "\w", "X", True)
```

However, the result looks like -

```
XXXXX XXXXXXXX

XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXX.
XX, XXXXX XXXX, XXXXXX XXXXXX, XXXXXXX XXXXXXX, XXXXXXXXX
XXXXX : XXX-XXX-XXXX
XXX :
XXXXX : XXXXXX@XXXXXX.XX
```

I'd like this to show the first character in every word. Any help out there?

Comment: Classic ASP? Really? I'd say you're out of luck because I'm willing to bet Classic ASP (unlike ASP.NET) does not support variable repetition inside lookbehind assertions which you'd definitely need to achieve this.

Comment: I'd just do it without regex... read through the stering character by character and keep a boolean of whether to pass the real character or an X to output. Then as you go through whitespace means the next character is real. You can also program certain characters (like @ or .) to pass straight through always. Much easier than all this messing around with regex. :)

Comment: The answer is in `GetRef` and the ability of the Regex engine used by VBScript to call a function for matches found in a replace function.  However I haven't got the time right now to write out in full, kudos to the other answerers who can post an answer demonstrating what I'm outlining before I get round to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach gets close:

```
Function AnonymiseWord(m, p, s)

   AnonymiseWord = Left(m, 1) & String(Len(m) - 1, "X")

End Function 


Function AnonymiseText(input)

    Dim rgx: Set rgx = new RegExp
    rgx.Global = True
    rgx.Pattern = "\b\w+?\b"

    AnonymiseText = rgx.Replace(input, GetRef("AnonymiseWord"))

End Function
```

This might get you close enough to what you need otherwise the basic approach is sound but you may need to fiddle with that pattern to get it match exactly the stretches of text you want to put through `AnonymiseWord`.

Comment: Wow, I never knew `RegExp.Replace` could take a function reference like that.  The only semi-official mention of it I could find was in an [MSDN Technical Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974619.aspx#scripting12_topic4).

Comment: Thanks Tony. This is the one I ended up using. Appreciate your help. Although, I would love it if I could somehow ignore uppercase letters from being anonymised. Im still trying to find out how to do that.

Comment: Very nice use of the regexp.replace. I didn't know that usage was allowed. But why not use `string(xCount)` for character repeating as in `Function AnonymiseWord(m, p, s) : AnonymiseWord = Left(m, 1) & String("X", len(m)-1): End Function`?

Comment: @AutomatedChaos: Why, indeed.  Because I had forgetten that this function exists in VBScript (I spend most of my time in C# these days).  Excellent suggestion, edited accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in .NET it would be easy:

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, 
    @"(?<=         # Assert that there is before the current position...
     \b            # a word boundary
     \w            # one alphanumeric character (= first letter/digit/underscore)
     [\w.@-]*      # any number of alnum characters or ., @ or -
    )              # End of lookbehind
    [\p{L}\p{N}]   # Match any letter or digit to be replaced", 
    "X", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

The result, though, would be slightly different than what you wrote:

```
"JXXXX JXXX JXXXXX 

S.X. IXXXXXXXXX CXXXX  
D-XXXX, FXXXX PXXXX, PXXXX 4-X, 
SXXXXXX, PXXXX
JXXXX
PXXXX : 9X-XXX-XXXXXXX FXX : 9X-XXX-XXXXXX
eXXXX : sXXXXX_XX@XXXXX.XXX"
```

(observe that `Fax` has also been changed to `FXX`)

Without .NET, you could try something like

```
orgstr = ereg_replace("\b(\w)[\w.@-]*", "\1XXXX", True); // not sure about the syntax here, you possibly need double backslashes
```

which would give you

```
"JXXXX JXXXX JXXXX 

SXXXX IXXXX CXXXX  
DXXXX, FXXXX PXXXX, PXXXX 4XXXX, 
SXXXX, PXXXX
JXXXX
PXXXX : 9XXXX FXXXX : 9XXXX
eXXXX : sXXXX"
```

You won't get it better than that with a single regex.

Comment: Oh. Awesome. You did better than me. Thanks much for that. Let me try and translate your expression into asp. Whats the @ on the second line of your code? Is that .NET syntax or a part of the regular expression?

Comment: It's not going to work in ASP Classic, only in ASP.NET, because it does not support the `*` quantifier inside lookbehind, which you need if you want to replace every single relevant letter with an X. The `@` is C# syntax for a verbatim string so the backslashes don't have to be escaped.

Comment: Dang! Thanks for the insight mate. So, whats my alternative?

Comment: I've added another version. If that doesn't work as-is, try it with doubled backslashes (`"\\b(\\w)..."`).

Comment: Yeah. The call needed one change. $1 instead of \1. Like -     orgstr = ereg_replace("\b(\w)[\w.@-]*", "$1XXXX", True); But, as you correctly note, we are also always seeing four Xs in each word irrespective of the original word length. I think we're getting close here.

Comment: @TimPietzcker I have no idea what regex features classic ASP is supporting, but if it does support lookbehind, but only fixed length (thats what I understood from your answer), then why not turn it around and use a fixed length negative lookbehind? See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea about classic ASP, but if it does support (negative) lookbehinds and the only problem is the quantifier in the lookbehind, then why not turn it around and do it this way:

```
(?<!^)(?<!\s)[a-zA-Z0-9]
```

and replace with "X".

Means, replace every letter and number if there is not a whitespace or not the start of the string/row before.

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?300lr)

Comment: Good idea, if lookbehind is supported. I fear it isn't, though, because it appears to be based on VBScript.

Answer (score 0):

Although I love regular expressions, you could do it without them, especially because VBScript does not support look behind.

```
Dim mystring, myArray, newString, i, j
Const forbiddenChars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
myString = "James John Junior   S.D. Industrial Corpn   D-2341, Focal Point, Phase 4-a,  Sarsona, Penns Japan Phone : 92-161-4633248 Fax : 92-161-253214 email : swerte_60@laher.com"
myArray = split(myString, " ")

For i = lbound(myArray) to ubound(myArray)
    newString = left(myArray(i), 1)
    For j = 2 to len(myArray(i))
        If instr(forbiddenChars, mid(myArray(i), j, 1)) > 0 Then
            newString = newString & "X"
        else
            newString = newString & mid(myArray(i), j, 1)
        End If
    Next
    myArray(i) = newString
Next

myString = join(myArray, " ")
```

It doesn't cope with the VbNewLine character, but you will get the idea. You can do an extra split on the VbNewLine character, iterate through all elements and split each element on the space for example.